# Kafka: Alternative to creating multiple consumer groups when reading from earliest offset

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, quarkus

I'm building a microservice (using Quarkus framework for Java). When the service boots up, it will read messages from a topic (using a consumer) from the earliest offset and these messages will populate a cache (HashMap). What I've learnt is that if my service needs to restart, I have to put the consumer into an individual consumer group which needs to have a unique group id. The group ID would be a UUID in this case.

So each time I restart, the group ID will be a UUID and the consumer will always read from the earliest offset. The problem we find is that there are a large number of old consumer groups laying around in the cluster, largely because we've restarted the service a number of times.

I'm researching for ways for us to always read from the earliest offset, but **without** the need to create a unique consumer group each time the system restarts. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is the config in the application.properties:

```
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.topic=data.cache.topic
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.value.deserializer=com.cache.DataCacheDeserializer
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.security.protocol=SSL
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.ssl.truststore.type=JKS
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.ssl.truststore.location=cert/certs
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.group.id=cache-${quarkus.uuid}
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.value-deserialization-failure-handler=deserialisation-failure-handler
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

Here is the consumer:

```
@Blocking("cache-consumer-pool")
@Incoming("cache-consumer")
public void populateCacheConsumer(final DataCache payload) {
    if (payload != null) {
        dataCacheMap.put(payload.getOid(), payload);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`auto.offset.reset` will only be used when the group doesn't already have offsets. Therefore, create no group / commit no offsets (set `enable.auto.commit=false` and don't commit manually if you are), and it'll always start at the beginning without over populating the cluster with random groups...

And/or manually call `consumer.seekToBeginning()`.

Also, you probably shouldn't be manually making a HashMap anyway from a Consumer. This is exactly what a State Store is for - https://kafka.apache.org/35/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#state-stores

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer. That is useful information. Regarding your last point, it is a fair point.
Would anyone know if this is possible to achieve with the Quarkus framework? If not, I can look into using the Kafka Client API. Quarkus would be preferred however

Comment: I don't use Quarkus, but I remember seeing it is possible to access the consumer directly in the docs. You should also be able to set the `onPartitionsAssigned` callback on the consumer from somewhere - https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#consumer-rebalance-listener

Answer (score 0):

In Quarkus you can simply configure your Reactive Messaging incoming channel to not commit any offsets, using the [`commit-strategy` attribute](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#commit-strategies). `ignore` will not perform any offset commits and continue consuming from the topic:

```
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.connector=smallrye-kafka
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.topic=data.cache.topic
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.commit-strategy=ignore
mp.messaging.incoming.cache-consumer.auto.offset.reset=earliest
```

As for the consumer group.id, Quarkus automatically configures it to the `quarkus.application.name` property, so you'll get a group.id per application which won't change with restarts.

Comment: Hi @Ozan Günalp, thanks for your comment. I did try adding the commit-strategy=ignore property and removed the group ID property, but it seems that the consumer will still not read from the beginning when I restart my service. Yes it does use application name as the default consumer group. I have updated my question with more code to paint a full picture. Am I doing anything wrong? Any advice would be great. thanks.

Comment: Did you check if there are some consumer offsets previously committed?

Comment: Ah yes, I realised that the existing consumer group (recording the offset) already existed, so I created a new consumer group (with the commit-strategy=ignore) for this specific topic and that worked. Thanks!

One last question - I have other topics where I need them to record their offsets. For this to work, I had to put those topics into a separate consumer group and put this topic (data.cache.topic) into it's own consumer group. If I mix all these topics into 1 consumer group, the data.cache.topic doesn't read from the beginning on bootup. Does that sound right? Thanks for your help

Comment: The consumer group offsets are per topic, so I suggest that you inspect committed offsets using the [kafka-consumer-groups-sh](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka/operations-tools/kafka-tools.html#kafka-consumer-groups-sh) cli